# Does ANTLR provide semantics

Tags: java, python, compiler-construction, antlr, semantics

I am currently using a Python 2.5 sample from the ANTLR website. I'm actually wondering if the grammar already produces semantics as well.If there is none, what can I do or what can I use(tools) for generating semantics for python after parsing it with ANTLR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tool to generate a language's semantics, that's something you have to implement yourself.

Now that you have parsed Python code, you can do some necessary processing first, output it as Python code again and use an existing implementation of the Python language for execution.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue on how I am going to do the semantics, could you suggest any resource I could use to create semantics?

Comment: The language is described in the Python Language Reference: http://docs.python.org/reference/ It's your best bet for learning the semantics of the Python language.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR handles the parsing, but not the semantics; it's a parser generation tool, after all. If you added semantics, you'd have a full python implementation (modulo fleshing out the libraries).

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR allows you to specify semantics in terms of actions associated with grammar rules. For simple tasks this may be convenient, but for larger grammars all you usually do is to generate an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), i.e. a representation of what you parsed that's more convenient to handle from within a program than a very long string.

Whether or how much of this is contained in the example you are using is rather hard to say without seeing the code ;-)

Comment: import_as_name
    :   NAME (NAME NAME)?
 ; is this a sample of semantics?

Comment: No this is a syntax rule, i.e. a description of how a correct program is formed. Semantics would be code to find the module mentioned in the `import` statement and start reading instructions from it.